# How to enable JS Compiling in Enduro.js

Tags: node.js, enduro.js

I need to put somme JS Functions in my Enduro.js project.

So I added my functions in /assets/js/main.js (which content is "// put your js here :-)/***" after Enduro.js new project setup).

I installed babel as advised :

```
npm install --save-dev babel-cli babel-preset-env
```

Enable JS compiling as advised in /enduro.json :

```
"babel": {
    "presets": ["env"]
}
```

I can see now "js compiling started & js compiling finished" messages in console, but still, my functions don't work (I can write trash in /assets/js/main.js and I get no error reporting in console).

I guess something is going wrong, main.js is not compiled, so what is the proper way to enable js compiling in enduro.js ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the default /assets/js/main.js is not included by default...
You have to manually include it in your html file (index.hbs by default)